# onLocationChanged is not called from IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, alarm

I have an AlarmManager that triggers every 30 minutes to an IntentService, and this intent service is to get the user's location each time. I have 2 ways of getting location: first it checks the getLastKnownLocation(), and if it was within the last 2 minutes it uses that, *this part works perfectly*.

The second way is if the last location was old or returns null, in which I want to get the new location once. For some reason *this never calls onLocationChanged().* This results in my IntentService not returning coordinates much of the time, it only returns them if the getLastKnownLocation() was recent.

Here is my code for how it is set up, why is it that if I want to get a new location, it is never called? Check the comments in the code to see what is called and what is never called.

```
LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private final double MIN_COORD_DIFF = 0.0006;

    public CoordinateAlarmReceiver(){
        super("CoordinateAlarmReceiver");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //THIS IS CALLED CORRECTLY
        MyLog.i("coordinate alarm received");

        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        //if last location was in past 2 minutes, use that
        if(lastLocation != null && lastLocation.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000) {
            //THIS IS CALLED CORRECTLY
            storeLocation(lastLocation);
            MyLog.i("Last location was recent, using that");
        }
        else {  //otherwise get new location
            //THIS IS CALLED CORRECTLY
            MyLog.i("Last location was old, getting new location");
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //THIS IS NEVER CALLED
                    MyLog.i("Got new coordinates");
                    storeLocation(location);
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                }
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Service instead of a IntentService. The IntentService finish when complete the task however, the service is running and can listen the location change events. Try to use a service.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: This works great, I wasn't aware of the difference thank you!